# I want to make effect similar to resizing top view on contacts app?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Native contacts app has interesting effect - when user tries to scroll, the scroll view pushes the top view with avatar and only when top view is in "small mode" it is scrolled up.

[image]

[image]

I was able to resize view on scrolling, via `didScroll` method. But problem is, content offset is also changing while i push the top vied. In native contacts, content offset changes only when top view is in "small mode"

Any suggestions, how did they made this?

Comment: Is the top view embedded as a header view in the table view or is it a view outside of the table view on top of it and you just change the constraints?

Comment: In guess you shouldn't change the offset but initially the inset of the tableView and have the top view seperate under a transparent navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounty answer is good, but it still gives somewhat choppy solution to this problem. If you want exacly like native this is your solution. I have been playing a lot lately with collection views, and have gained much more experience. One of the things that I found is that this problem can easily be solved with custom layout:

```
class CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    let minHeightForHeader: CGFloat = 50
    let offsetFromTop: CGFloat = 20

    override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

        // get current attributes
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: elementKind, at: indexPath)

        // get first section
        if let attributes = attributes, elementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader && indexPath.section == 0 {
            if let collectionView = collectionView {

                // now check for content offset
                var frame = attributes.frame
                let yOffset = collectionView.contentOffset.y
                if yOffset >= -offsetFromTop {
                    let calculatedHeight = frame.size.height - (yOffset + offsetFromTop)
                    let maxValue = minHeightForHeader > calculatedHeight ? minHeightForHeader : calculatedHeight
                    frame.size.height = maxValue
                    attributes.frame = frame
                }
                else {
                    frame.origin.y = offsetFromTop + yOffset
                    attributes.frame = frame
                }
            }
            return attributes
        }

        // default return
        return attributes
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Just replace your default layout with this custom class and add this line somewhere in your setup method

```
flowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

Voila!

EDIT: Just one more optional method for clipping part, when you scroll to certain part, scroll might continue or return:

```
override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        if let collectionView = collectionView {
            let yOffset = collectionView.contentOffset.y
            if yOffset + offsetFromTop >= maxHeightForHeader / 2 &&  yOffset + offsetFromTop < maxHeightForHeader && !(velocity.y < 0) || velocity.y > 0{
                return CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: maxHeightForHeader - minHeightForHeader - offsetFromTop)
            }
            if yOffset + offsetFromTop < maxHeightForHeader / 2 &&  yOffset + offsetFromTop > 0 || velocity.y < 0 {
                return CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: -offsetFromTop)
            }
        }
        return proposedContentOffset
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample project of how you could do it:
https://github.com/lukaswuerzburger/resizeable-tableview-header

You simply have a view controller with a table view and a custom view (resizable header) in it. On `scrollViewDidScroll` you change the height constraint.

<sub>PS: The transitions between the master and detail view controller are not prefect, but maybe someone can help me with that. The change of `navigationBar`'s `backgroundImage` and `shadowImage` doesn't really work animated when popping back to the master view controller.</sub>

Comment: Exacly what i was looking for. You earned this bounty ;-) But i can award you in 10 hours